# How do I make an API Call in an iOS Xamarin Forms application on Launch?

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I have a Xamarin Forms app which on all platforms will hit an API on launch to see if a specific server is accessible.

```
protected override async void OnAppearing()
        {
            base.OnAppearing();
            _model.LoginEnabled = false;
            await Device.InvokeOnMainThreadAsync(async () =>
            {
                try
                {
                    await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3));
                    var apiService = DependencyService.Get<IApiService>();
                    _model.IsOnline = await apiService.CheckIfOnline();
                    if (_model.IsOnline)
                    {
                        var downloader = DependencyService.Get<IDownloader>();
                        await downloader.AttemptToDownloadContentJson();
                    }
                    _model.LoginEnabled = true;
                } 
                catch
                {

                    _model.LoginEnabled = true;
                }
            });
        }
```

Here is the check for if online for iOS implementation of the interface:

```
public async Task<bool> CheckIfOnline()
        {
            try
            {
                var pathsProvider = DependencyService.Get<IPathsProvider>();
                var downloadUrl = pathsProvider.GetDownloadUrl();
                HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create($"{downloadUrl}api/about");
                request.Timeout = 5000;
                var response = (HttpWebResponse) await request.GetResponseAsync();
                return response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK;
            }
            catch
            {
                //Something went wrong
                return false;
            }
        }
```

_model.IsOnline binds to a text string in the navigation bar which shows "Online" if the api is available.

The expected result is the application opens on iOS, hits the API when its available and shows Online and downloads the "Content JSON". The actual result is that on launch, the application does not show the Online indicator until I navigate away from and back to that page. Then everything works as expected with online appearing and the relevant json being downloaded.

Everything works as expected on Android.

Is there any specific setting to allow for https REST API calls at launch? The target is a server on a closed network.

Edit:

- xaml that uses _model.LoginEnabled.

```
<NavigationPage.TitleView> 
        <Grid VerticalOptions="Fill">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="5*" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Label HorizontalOptions="Start" Text="Some Random Text" VerticalOptions="Center" TextColor="White" FontSize="28" Grid.Column="0"/>
            <Label HorizontalOptions="End" Text="Online" IsVisible="{Binding IsOnline}" Grid.Column="1"/>
        </Grid>
    </NavigationPage.TitleView>
```

- Line that sets BindingContext = ....

```
public LoginPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            _model = new LoginViewModel();
            _model.IsSyncing = false;
            BindingContext = _model;
        }
```

- Line(s) that declare _model. E.g. public MyModel _model { get; set; }

```
private readonly LoginViewModel _model;
```

- Declaration line of whatever class _model is. E.g. public class MyModel : INotifyPropertyChanged.

```
public class LoginViewModel : ObservableObject
```

- Line(s) in class of _model that declare LoginEnabled

```
        private bool _loginEnabled;
        public bool LoginEnabled
        {
            get { return _loginEnabled; }
            set { 
                    _loginEnabled= value;
                    OnPropertyChanged(nameof(LoginEnabled));
                }
        }
```

Comment: first, if you want it to occur on launch, it should go in the App OnStart method.  Second, if the API is just a basic REST request you shouldn't need to do so much work via DependencyService.  Finally, if the model update is not updating your UI, it is often a MainThread of INPC issue.  Since you didn't post any model code I can't give specific advice on that.

Answer (score 0):

Fix #1: Please **add to question** FIVE pieces of code:

- xaml that uses `_model.LoginEnabled`.
- Line that sets `BindingContext = ...`.
- Line(s) that declare `_model`.  E.g. `public MyModel _model { get; set; }`
- Declaration line of whatever class _model is. E.g. `public class MyModel : INotifyPropertyChanged`.
- Line(s) in class of _model that declare `LoginEnabled`.

ALL of this information is involved in displaying the relevant UI.
If any of these are not correctly done, that might cause the symptom you see.

HINT: When you ask future questions, try to think of any code that could possibly be relevant to the symptom. Often, the problem isn't where you think it is.

---

Fix #2: If all of the above are correct, the fix may be as simple as removing one `await`. (Also implies calling a different invoke method.) Change:

```cs
await Device.InvokeOnMainThreadAsync(async () =>
```

to:

```cs
Device.InvokeOnMainThread(async () =>
```

EXPLANATION: The `await` forced `OnAppearing` to suspend until the `Invoke...` completed.

Removing `await` **queues** the `Invoke...` code, allowing `OnAppearing` to return immediately, the page to draw, and most importantly, ensures Xamarin Forms is in a state where it correctly responds to the bound variable change `_model.LoginEnabled = true`.

SIDE-EFFECT: This means the page will display its "not logged in" state, until server responds. Therefore, you might want to add a "busy indicator" that says "Loading ..." or "Waiting for server ..." etc.

---

Optional: Ensure non-UI work is OFF of UI thread:

```cs
Task.Run(async () =>
{
    try
    {
        // Can remove Task.Delay.
        ...
    } 
    catch {}
    
    Device.InvokeOnMainThread( () =>
        _model.LoginEnabled = true );
});
```

Comment: See edits. Will try to remove await.

Comment: Declarations all look good.

Comment: NOTE: The `Task.Delay` can be removed. Or reduced to 50 to 500 ms. Lower values are fine if firing off the server query doesn't take much time. You've put all your code on UI thread, which can cause UI delays. I'll add alternative that Task.Runs most of it.

Comment: When removing `await`, you might as well change which method you call, to avoid compiler complaint. Call `InvokeOnMainThread` instead of `InvokeOnMainThreadAsync`.